# Automatically open a virtual environment when calling a python script in Windows

Tags: python, virtualenv

This question has been asked before, but the answers are all several years old and I could not get any to work for me, so I would appreciate some help.

The question is simple, really: I have a python script, and a virtual environment I want it to run in when I double-click it, or call it from another program. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you must add packages directory address to your `sys.path`

`sys.path` a built-in variable within the sys module. It contains a list of directories that the interpreter will search in for the required module.

add line below to top of your script, now you can double click on script file and every thing must work fine

```py
import sys; sys.path.append("./<environment path>/Lib/site-packages")
```

this is simple solution however, as [sinoroc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11138259/sinoroc) said it's not good solution because in this situation you are using system interpreter not virtual environment interpreter so i wouldn't be surprised if things don't work as expected.

---

also you can download all packages that you need and extract them into single folder and add that folder to `sys.path`

first download packages you need with command below

```
pip download <package names> --dest <directory name>
```

for example:

```
pip download requests --dest packages
```

at the end add folder contain you packages to your path

```py
import sys; sys.path.append("./<packages directory>")
```

---

## Recommended Solution

the best solution is that write little batch script for windows or shell script for linux that automatically active virtual environment and then run your script

first create file with **.bat** extention for windows or **.sh** extension for linux and then add line below to it

for **.bat** file

```
<environment path>\Scripts\activate && python <script name>.py
```

for **.sh** file

```sh
source <environment path>/bin/activate && python <script name>.py
```

now you can click on this batch script ***.bat** file or shell script ***.sh** file and everything work's fine

Comment: Thank you, I tried something like this before but your code worked. Hopefully it's enough :)

Comment: That's a bit of a risky technique. Assuming the default Python interpreter is the same (or a compatible one) used to create the virtual environment, it could work. But in a scenario where _1._ the virtual environment was created with a Python 3.6 32 bits and _2._ the Python interpreter picked up by the operating system when double clicking is Python 3.8 64 bits then I wouldn't be surprised if things don't wok as expected.

Comment: Yeah, it's not perfect, but I only want this to work on a couple of my own machines, so I think it'll be fine enough

Answer (score -1):

Some ideas

**Shebang**

Place a *shebang* pointing to the Python interpreter inside the virtual environement with the full path at the top of the script.

```
#!/path/to/my/venv/bin/python

import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

**Shell/batch script**

Write a shell script wrapping the call to the actual Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

/path/to/my/venv/bin/python /path/to/my/script.py
```

**Python wrapper**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

command = [
    '/path/to/my/venv/bin/python',
    '/path/to/my/script.py',
]
subprocesss.check_call(command)
```

Comment: If possible I would like to use shebangs, but I can't get them to work, for some reason. Do they work with Windows? Should my path start with #!/C:/users.. or  #!/venv/scripts/python as my venv is in the same folder as my project?

Comment: Not sure exactly how it is on Windows. You might want to read this page for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, which was about Windows

Comment: @xdavidliu At least the third suggestion should work straight away or with very little modification. Indeed Python on Windows is supposed to be able to interpret this shebang line. And the second suggestion is quite easy to adapt into a Windows batch, it is just one line.